# how to write an sbt plugin to launch the app with an agent

Tags: scala, plugins, sbt

I would like to create an sbt plugin for my project before I open source it.

The project attaches a Java agent to the start of running an application, to instrument it for various types of profiling. The agent writes out text files for later processing.

I would like to be able to write an sbt plugin that can

- have an alternative to `run` called `runWithProfiling` which launches a new java process, with the agent added to the argument list, and passing all the users commands.
- on exit, I then want to invoke some arbitrary post-processing code to produce an HTML report

I know roughly how to create the new command, but I don't know how to best implement an alternative to `run`... I don't want to re-invent the wheel by copying all the code that `run` does. Is there a way I can invoke `run` but ensure that my parameters are passed (one time) and that it is definitely a new java process?

Also, being able to do the same for the tests would be great.

**UPDATE**: this is the code that I currently have, but it suffers from several problems, marked up as `TODO`s

```scala
import sbt._
import Keys._
import sbt.Attributed.data

object LionPlugin extends Plugin {

  val lion = TaskKey[Unit]("lion", "Run a main class with lions-share profiling.")

  override val projectSettings = Seq(
    fork := true,
    javaOptions ++= Seq(
      "-Xloggc:gc.log", "-XX:+PrintGCDetails", "-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps",
      "-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution", "-XX:+PrintHeapAtGC"
      // TODO: need to get hold of the local jar file for a particular artifact
      // IMPL: pass the jar as the agent
    ),
    lion <<= (
      runner,
      fullClasspath in Runtime,
      mainClass in Runtime,
      streams in Runtime
      ) map runLion
  )

  // TODO: update to a task that can take parameters (e.g. number of repeats, profiling settings)
  def runLion(runner: ScalaRun, cp: Classpath, main: Option[String], streams: TaskStreams): Unit = {
    assert(runner.isInstanceOf[ForkRun], "didn't get a forked runner... SBT is b0rk3d")
    println("RUNNING with " + runner.getClass)

    // TODO: ask user if main is None, like 'run' does
    val m = main.getOrElse("Scratch")

    // TODO: get the user's arguments
    val args = Nil

    runner.run(m, data(cp), args, streams.log)

    // IMPL: post-process and produce the report

    println("FINISHED")
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugin authors need to abide by an unwritten Hippocratic Oath, which is "first, do no harm." Your implementation currently forces itself to every subproject and mutates `fork` and `javaOptions` of the default behavior, which I think is dangerous. I think you need to duplicate the `run` parameters scoped to your task so the default settings are unharmed.

> ```
> // TODO: update to a task that can take parameters (e.g. number of repeats, profiling settings)
> ```

See [Plugins Best Practices](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Extending/Plugins-Best-Practices.html) and existing plugins like [sbt-appengine](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-appengine/blob/master/src/main/scala/AppenginePlugin.scala) for an example.

In sbt-appengine `devServer` is an input task that you can set a bunch of parameters.

```
gae.devServer       := {
  val args = startArgsParser.parsed
  val x = (products in Compile).value
  AppEngine.restartDevServer(streams.value, (gae.reLogTag in gae.devServer).value,
    thisProjectRef.value, (gae.reForkOptions in gae.devServer).value,
    (mainClass in gae.devServer).value, (fullClasspath in gae.devServer).value,
    (gae.reStartArgs in gae.devServer).value, args,
    packageWar.value,
    (gae.onStartHooks in gae.devServer).value, (gae.onStopHooks in gae.devServer).value)
}
```

As you see the gut of the code is actually implemented in a method under `AppEngine` object, so someone else can reuse your stuff potentially.
Many of the parameters into the method (in this case `restartDevServer`) are scoped to `gae.devServer` task like `(mainClass in gae.devServer)`.

How do you intend the plugin to be set up by the build users? Are they going to enable it once as a global plugin and use the same settings everywhere, or are they going to enable it for each build in `project/lion.sbt`? [Plugins Best Practices](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Extending/Plugins-Best-Practices.html)'s recommendation is to provide `baseLionSettings` and `lionSettings` so the build user can pick and chose which subproject would have the `lion` task enabled.

As per actual running goes, you might want to take a look at reusing the code from [sbt-revolver](https://github.com/spray/sbt-revolver) similar to what I did in sbt-appengine.

Comment: this is very useful, thanks! I would very much like to allow users to set this on a per-module basis, and to leave the user's fork/javaOptions untouched. I am afraid I am still no closer to knowing how to do this, even after reading your source. I originally had e.g. `fork in lion := true`, but that was being ignored.

Comment: although, I'll steal your approach and use `Fork.java` directly... that means I never mutate either setting.

Answer (score 1):

See “How can I create a custom run task, in addition to run?” at http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/faq.html . In your custom task, you'll want to set `fork` to true in order to launch a fresh JVM.

Comment: this was only the tip of the iceberg... actually calling `fullRunTask` is tricky. It is a `Setting` and I don't know how to actually call it...

Comment: apologies, unmarking answer so that I can update with more details