# File of one of the sbt plugin's dependencies

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt, ivy

I need to get hold of the `File` reference to a specific artifact during the setup phase of my sbt's plugin.

I've tried:

1. obtaining the ivy home directory, but that basically means assuming where ivy will place the files (they could be even be in a local maven)
2. parsing `System.getProperty("java.class.path")`, but it only contains the `sbt-launch` jar
3. obtaining the resolved sbt jars from the `update.value` setting, but it doesn't have any of the plugin's jars in the list! (only the jars for the application being compiled)

Short of invoking the Ivy API manually, is there any way to get the `File` to the plugin's jar dependency?

NOTE: This is a very specific part of [how to write an sbt plugin to launch the app with an agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23029910/) factored out into a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

got it! adding the dependency explicitly within the source reveals its resolved path:

```scala
override val projectSettings = Seq(
  libraryDependencies += "com.github.fommil.lion" %% "agent" % "1.0-SNAPSHOT",
  javaOptions ++= Seq(s"-Dhack=${update.value}}")
)
```

has a reference in it!